# Can I change the Logon type of a windows service through GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, user-accounts

We are using a custom windows service which does some task and runs as Local System account. For technical reasons in our project, we want to change the logon type of our windows service to a domain user account.

The issue is that we have few hundreds of VMs in our infra where this service is running as Local System account. It is not feasible to manually change the logon types in all the VMs. I am wondering if this is something that can be done from GPO? Or are their any third party tools that can accomplish this ?

Comment: It can be done via GPP. But: "a few hundred VMs in our infra" and no configuration or VM management other than GPOs/GPPs?

Comment: We do have, have Vsphere and linked clone technology where we can spawn VMs from a parent VM. However, we have one usecase to support where few hundred VMs NOT created from same snapshot is used in a pool. Would you elaborate a bit how it is possible from GPP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a GPO for your OU
2. Go to `Computer Configuration -> Preferences -> Control Panel -> Settings -> Services`
3. Create a service preference with `Action -> New -> Service`
4. Enter your service's name
5. Configure your wanted options (Account, startup type, timeout, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, it is working, however I noticed that I need to restart all the VMs for the change to be seen. Is there some way to overcome this or is it not possible?

Comment: Usually a `gpupdate /force` (or waiting) is enough, but in this case I'm not sure.

Comment: ok, got it, I need to run gpupdate /force on the VMs and the changes take affect without restart.

Comment: I have a follow up question on this. The above approach is working for me. Now the scenario is when the password of that configured user changes in Active Directory. I modified the GPO and put the new password. After that I did a gpupdate /force on that VM, but i noticed that the new password does-not take affect. I also restarted that VM but still the old password is configured for that account. Is that expected ?