# How to change the password of a windows service through GPO

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, user-accounts

THis is a follow up to my previous question here --[Can I change the Logon type of a windows service through GPO](https://serverfault.com/questions/989080/can-i-change-the-logon-type-of-a-windows-service-through-gpo)

So I have a custom windows service which is configured to run in a specified user account through GPO. Now the scenario is how do we handle password changes for that user account.

I did the following--
Edit the GPO configured , go to Computer Configuration -> Preferences -> Control Panel -> Settings -> Services and change the password field of that service to the updated one.
Also, i selected Service Action -- Restart service
 After that I ran gpupdate on the VM, but the service is still using the old password. Looks like if the user name is the same, and just the password changes, the GPO does-not update the password.

Any thoughts on how to handle this would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess what you really need is `Managed Service Accounts`: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/09/10/managed-service-accounts-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will read about this Managed service account. so is it certain that we cannot change the password of that user through GPO?

Comment: As a possible workaround, try replacing the GPO with a new one instead of editing the existing one.

Comment: Had tried that, but it didnt work.